# How can I get the value of dynamic checkboxes in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox, ngmodel

I create a variable number of checkboxes in my angular application.
This is my component.ts:

```
  pathMap = new Map<string, string>();

  [...]
constructor(private homeservice: HomeService) {

}
ngOnInit(): void {...}

   showContracts() {
   return this.homeservice.showContracts(this.contractsPath).subscribe((data:string)=>{this.splitPath(data)})
  }

  private splitPath(path:string){
    this.pathMap.clear()
    let fullPath = path.split(",");
    for(let index = 0; index <fullPath.length; index++) {
      this.ignoreArray.set(fullPath[index],false)
      if (fullPath[index] !== "") {
        if (path.includes('/'))
          this.pathMap.set(fullPath[index].substring(fullPath[index].lastIndexOf('/') + 1), fullPath[index])
        else
          this.pathMap.set(fullPath[index].substring(fullPath[index].lastIndexOf('\\') + 1), fullPath[index])
      }
    }
  }
```

And this is my html code:

```
 <div >
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" id="ignoreContracts" (click)="showContracts()" >Select contracts to be ignored</button>
        </div>
        <div id="slider">
        <div  id="dynamicCheckBox" *ngFor="let data of this.pathMap | keyvalue">
            <mat-checkbox color="primary"  >
              {{data.key}}
            </mat-checkbox>
          <br><br>
        </div>
```

I want to see which checkbox is checked and which is not. I've been thinking about using [(ngModel)] in some way but I can't figure out how.

Comment: This isn’t really a job for ngmodel. You’re really going to have to do it as a reactive form

Comment: Can your object `pathMap`  include a property `isTrue: boolean` using `.map` . and then use that to check which mat-checkbox is `checked` on `unchecked`. If it's allowed in the use case, I think I can help you, otherwise, as the guy before me mentioned, Reactive Forms is the way to go.

Comment: I solve the problem using Reactive Forms.